# Integral of $\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-\sin(2x)}}$?

Tags: real-analysis, integration

Need to find integral

$$ \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-\sin(2x)}}$$.

but getting nowhere.

Comment: I have tried making v=tg(x) and developing I have the integral of dt/((1-t)(sqrt(1+(t^2))). By parts it follows the integral of arcsinh(t)/(1-t)dt, then I just get very confused.

Comment: Try following one of the hints in the ensuing answers. You'll do great.

Comment: This question got flagged as "low-quality because of its length and content." The only thing I would change would be to show  your previous work in the question itself instead of just a comment; seeing what you already tried, the question looks OK to me.

Comment: I've arrived to an interesting kinda' answer but I don't know how to get the picture of my work...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

setting $u=2x$ then we have $du=2dx$ and our integral is $$\frac{1}{2}\int \frac{du}{\sqrt{1-\sin(u)}}$$ with $s=1-\sin(u)$ we get $ds=-\cos(u)du$ and we get $$\frac{1}{2}\int \frac{-ds}{\sqrt{(2-s)s}}$$ now we get by setting $p=2-s,dp=-ds$ the integral $$-\frac{1}{2}\int \frac{dp}{(p-2)\sqrt{p}}$$ and with $w=\sqrt{p}$
and $dw=\frac{1}{2\sqrt{p}}dp$ we get $$-\int \frac{1}{w^2-2}dw$$. Can you solve this integral?

Comment: Yes. That's -arctgh(w). Thanks Doctor.

Comment: should i post you the result? it looks a little bit ugly

Comment: No. I already took it from here. I previously did something like this but my professor told me inverse hyperbolic trigonometric functions appear, so I did what I commented in the question.

Comment: Is a sqrt(v) missing from the change from u to s?

Answer (score 2):

**HINT**: We have $\sqrt{1-\sin(2x)} = \vert \cos(x) - \sin(x)\vert$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:  $$\sin^2(z/2)=\frac12 (1-\cos z)=\frac12 (1-\sin(z+\pi /2))$$